# Sudden problem with WiFi internet access with one specific Ubuntu 22.04 device with one specific router

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (with Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201) that suddenly it just can't access the internet with my home WiFi. It was completely unexpected because it was working fine up until now, and when it started failing I was in an online meeting. It's also peculiar because it sometimes starts working perfectly (ping 8.8.8.8 has a 0% packet loss with <15ms), other times it just goes very slowly (ping 8.8.8.8 has a 20% - 70% packet loss, with >110ms), and other times there's no connection at all (ping 8.8.8.8 has a 100% packet loss, or >3000ms).

[image: ping test on my computer]

The weird thing is:

- I have another laptop with Ubuntu 22.10 where my internet connection was fine (ping 8.8.8.8 consistently has a 0% packet loss with < 15ms). So it seems to be a problem with my computer.
- It works completely fine when connecting to my Android hotspot instead of my WiFi. So it seems to be a problem with my WiFi??

Things that don't work:

- Restarting the computer.
- Restarting the NetworkManager service.
- Restarting the router.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening??

Answer (score -1):

It was docker. It had a network bridge that overlapped the IP of my router. Running `docker network prune` temporarily fixes the problem. For a permanent solution look in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1504896/network-packet-loss-on-ubuntu-on-a-specific-network?newreg=76e02402134c4270a91fa2dab91acd68).